# Can't figure out where to set {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}

Tags: angularjs

I have been trying to set the responseType to 'arrayBuffer' in the following code, but I keep getting `Failed to load pdf document`

```
var resource =  ApiService.getResource('/cases/report');

   resource.get({caseId: self.CaseID,responseType:'arraybuffer'},function(data){
    var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);
   });
```

I have tried putting `{responseType: 'arraybuffer'}` in the getResource method along with a various other places in the get method, but I get the error `Failed to Load Pdf Document`

I also tried adding it here like:

```
var resource = $resource('url', {},{responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
```

but this doesn't work as well

Full code:

```
 function getResource(endpoint) {
        var resource = $resource(endpoint, null);
        return wrapActions(resource);
    }

  function wrapActions(resource) {
        var wrappedResource = resource;
        for (var i = 0; i < self.actions.length; i++) {
            self.wrapAction(wrappedResource, self.actions[i]);
        }

        // return modified copy of resource
        return wrappedResource;
    }


    function wrapAction(resource, action) {
        // copy original action
        resource['_' + action] = resource[action];

        // create new action wrapping the original and sending token
        resource[action] = function (data, success, error) {
            data = data || {};

            return resource['_' + action](
                angular.extend({}, data),
                function (response) {
                    handleSuccess(response, success);
                },
                function (response) {
                    handleError(response, error);
                }
            );
        };
    }

    function handleSuccess(response, callback) {
        if (callback) {
            callback(response);
        }
    }

    function handleError(response, callback) {
        if (typeof response.status !== 'undefined') {
            switch (response.status) {
                case '403' :
                case 403 :
                case '401' :
                case 401 :
                    handle401();
                    return;
            }
        }

        if (callback) {
            callback(response);
        }
    }

    function handle401() {
        if ($state.current.name != 'login') {
            AuthService.setRedirect($state.current.name, $stateParams);
        }

        AuthService.logout();
        $state.go('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reference what library you're using, if any. From what I can tell, these functions look like some internal code that either you or your company has written, so there's no way we'd know what the correct invocation would be unless you tell us.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Hi, I added more code

Comment: The $resource service can only return JavaScript objects or arrays depending on isArray. To get exotic objects such as ArrayBuffer or Blob, use the $http service. Or you can also try using XHR2